# A task from a Taskfile fails when ran from VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code, githooks, taskfile

In my project, I have the following `pre-commit` hook:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
task validate_lint
```

In addition, in my `Taskfile.yml` I have the following:

```yaml
  validate_lint:
    desc: Run black, flake8 and isort _validations_
    cmds:
      - poetry run black --check .
      - poetry run flake8 .
      - poetry run isort -c --df .
```

When I commit something from my terminal, the hook kicks in and runs the task properly. However, when committing from VScode, I get the following error:

```
task: [validate_lint] poetry run black --check .
Skipping .ipynb files as Jupyter dependencies are not installed.
You can fix this by running ``pip install "black[jupyter]"``
All done! ✨  ✨
6 files would be left unchanged.
task: [validate_lint] poetry run flake8 .
task: [validate_lint] poetry run isort -c --df .
Command not found: isort
task: Failed to run task "validate_lint": exit status 1
```

I must be missing something in the way the hook is executed when called from VScode. But I don't know what that thing is. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what was the problem, but reloading VScode solved it.